# Make elements to fade in when visible

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, window, visible

I'm using this jQuery plugin [One Page Scroll](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) and I would like to know how can I determine that the elements in different pages fade in when visible on the screen? Also it should be responsive as I adapted this plugin to work with Media-queries.

I've tryed to add fadeToggle `afterMove`, but it displays all the elements.

I've also spotted that the Plugin adds the `active` class to the element. Maybe I can target this? Please help, I'm novice with jQuery

Comment: looks like the plugin takes an `afterMove` callback where you would fade your elements in.

Comment: yes, but how do I define when on that page? I've tryed to use css display:none and then fadetoggle, but the result is that when the first page changes all the elemnts appear

Comment: Use the index that it passes to the callback.

Comment: Please edit the question with the details of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states that there is a configuration function called "afterMove".

```
$('#main').onepage_scroll({
  afterMove: function(index){
    //do your fadeIn here.
    $('section').eq(index).children().fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Comment: doesn't work. Display's all the pages at the same time. I need a specific one displayed when scrolled to that page.

Comment: Use the index properly.  within afterMove, $('section').eq(index).find('alltheelementsyouwanttotrigger').fadeIn();

Comment: What exactly should I write in index? I tryed to add numbers of pages, but it didn't work. Thanks,

Comment: It works, but I have to add `style="display:none"` to the element for it to function, can I do it adding a class?

Comment: I updated the code above.  Index is a parameter that's filled in onAfterMove, so it should be the index that is currently viewed.

Comment: In CSS, you should set your classes to display none if you want them invisible until they scroll to it.

Answer (score 0):

Get the window height, then on scroll determine if it is "within the window":

```
$(function(){
    var $item = $('.itemToShow'),
        $mainTop = $('.main').scrollTop();

    $(window).on({
        scroll:function(){
            if($(document).scrollTop() >= $mainTop){
                $item.fadeIn(300);
            } else {
                $item.fadeOut(300);
            }
        },
        resize:function(){
            $itemTop = $item.scrollTop();
        }
    });
});
```

This captures the `scrollTop` of the item (the integer value of pixels from the top you would need to "scroll down" to reach the top of the element), then when scrolling compares that number to the amount of pixels scrolled down. Once the scrolled down value is higher than the amount needed, it will fade in the item, and if you scroll back up (lessening the document scroll value), it will fade it out.

I updated the code to repopulate the `$mainTop` value based on resizing the window, and optimized it a bit. Should work though, I do practically this exact setup for my sticky menu setup.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I tryed to apply it to `.main`, but doesn't work.

Comment: @ArturasStrazdas updated my code and answer, hopefully providing a bit of a better explanation.